# ~/.ssh/config Host entry not honored when connecting via IP address

Tags: linux, ssh, configuration

I'm trying to connect to a Gateway via ssh.

In order to connect to the Gateway I write

```
  ssh root@ip_GW , where ip_GW is the ip of the Gateway.
```

So, in order to not always write the ip adress of the GW, i made an alias in the .ssh/config file like this ( I also made key to connect passwordless) :

```
  Host GW2

    #IdentitiesOnly=yes
     HostName ip_GW
     Identity file ~/.ssh/id_rsa_GW2
     User root
```

Now i can connect passwordless to the Gateway like this

```
  ssh GW2
```

and it works just fine

Now the problem is that, if I write again the specific ip_address of the GW like this

```
 ssh root@ip_GW , where ip_GW is the ip of the GW
```

it will give the error:

```
 Too many authentification failures
```

I really need to connect to the GateWay also using the specific ip_address What should I do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the IP address to the list of the host name patterns that should match the configuration section. Here, `GW2` and `203.0.113.1` will match:

```
Host GW2 203.0.113.1
    #IdentitiesOnly=yes
    HostName 203.0.113.1
    Identity file ~/.ssh/id_rsa_GW2
    User root
```

You can find this documented (briefly) with `man ssh_config`,

> **`Host`** Restricts the following declarations (up to the next `Host` or `Match` keyword) to be only for those hosts that match one of the patterns given after the keyword.  If more than one pattern is provided, they should be separated by whitespace. A single `*` as a pattern can be used to provide global defaults for all hosts. The host is usually the hostname argument given on the command line (see the `CanonicalizeHostname` keyword for exceptions).

Comment: Nice 

I also tried doing this

                  Host  ip_address
                          IdentitiesOnly=yes
                          HostName ip_address
                          User root



and it worked

I will also try your method

Comment: I tried your method too and this one also worked like a charm
Thank you !
Your method is better
Because I can use the same key to log passwordless

Comment: In my method I have created a different Host, hence I had to create a new key to log into ssh. Yours is better

Comment: @Ionescu another answer, perhaps?